# Need to write simple form data collection tool in python for local usage

Tags: python, forms, csv

I need to write a **simple** python application for data collection by a form. The form itself just needs

- a few textfields for name and address,
- a datefield
- and a choosebox/dropdown field.

The app will be run locally and the data should be saved locally in a plain csv file. No networking needed.

I've found that there many different ways to solve this problem:

- commandline-app,
- gui-app with tkinter/qt,
- microframeworks like flask or bottle,
- big frameworks like django.

Of course there definately are ways I haven't found yet. The main focus is **simplicity** and I need a pointer to the right direction: How can I implement this so that for example even unexperienced developers may add or change a field later?

Comment: Is networking a bad thing? Have you considered Google forms?

Comment: I know google forms and personally like networking but the requirements here are to collect, process and store data locally for data protection reasons.

Comment: As much as I cringe saying this, but If simplicity is the goal, just use a spreadsheet program. Create a two sheet spreadsheet. 1 sheet for data entry, 2nd sheet for in-cell dropdown references. Just know that after more than 5-10 people are doing this, it is not scalable.

Comment: The absolute simplest program would be a command line app using `input/raw_input`, but it won't be pretty. Have you tried this?

Comment: You are right, this would arguably be the most simplest implementation! But in terms of usability here maybe a bit to rudimentary. The user should at least be able to switch between the fields and change his input before submitting the whole record.

Answer (score 4):

The Simplest Form I can think of save it as `index.html` on the desktop then open it in your browser:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myfirstform" name='hello'>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
    <select id="some_dropdown1" name="some_dropdown">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" >Please select a name</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>

<input type='button' value='Submit form' onclick='submitDetailsForm()' />

<script>
    function submitDetailsForm() {
      var f = $("#myfirstform").serialize();
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/?'+ f)
        .then(r=> r.json())
        .then(j=> {
            console.log(j)
        })
    }
</script>
```

And the server save it as `server.py` and run `python server.py`:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import urlparse, json

# python2
# from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


class HandleRequests(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        # this line is important to understand for CORS
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        query_parms = urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query
        parsed = urlparse.parse_qs(query_parms)
        parsed['server_message'] = 'we gottem'
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(parsed))

host = 'localhost'
port = 8080
HTTPServer((host, port), HandleRequests).serve_forever()
```

IMHO, this is as simple as it gets, a python builtin, and jquery, which is basically an internet builtin.

Example input usage with response from server:

[image: no form validation, but super simple form]

Example output from server:

[image]

For more advanced usage consider:

```
    def do_POST(self):
        # Doesn't do anything with posted data
        self._set_headers()
        content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        self.wfile.write("received post request:<br>{}".format(post_body))

    def do_PUT(self):
        self.do_POST()
```

I leave figuring out how to write to a csv/tsv file.

Figure out how to write a basic router that allows you to create endpoints that send data back to your page, so you can populate the dropdown menu.

Some `if/else` statements in the `do_GET` should be sufficient.

I would prefer this as a starting point once you reach the limitations, and begin to learn how spaghetti gets made, then move into using flask, or something like cherrypy.

goodluck

Answer (score 3):

[WTForms](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms) should do the trick as a simple standalone form builder.

See the [crash course](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/crash_course.html) for examples to create the form you describe.